# Making second Request after first request with angular ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to upload two files by making one request for the first first and after  I do the second by sending an second file.But it seems that the second request doesn't  seems to be completing. I'm using ng-file-upload angular directive and the two files are being recognized by my model.

```
   $scope.send = function(files) {

                Upload.upload({
                    url: '/promotion/createPromotion',
                    data: { file: files.file1, name: files.name, description: files.description, startDate: files.start_date, endDate: files.end_date }

                }).success(function(resp) {

                    console.log(resp);

                    var idVar = resp.id;
                    console.log(idVar);

                    Upload.upload({
                        url: '/promotion/createImage',
                        data: { files: files.file2, id: idVar }
                    }).then(function(resp) {
                        console.log(resp.id);
                    }, function(resp) {

                    });
                }, function(resp) {
                    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                }, function(evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    // console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                });

            };
```

**Update**

after a little try, i found that  the three record were created successfully but in the four seems that the nested upload function triggered first and that's why is giving me an exception but even so; i don't know how to make it work properly

[image]

Comment: Why in first request you use `.success()` and with second request you use `.then()`? Try to be consistent

Comment: well,i'm trying to make a second request after the success of the first. Moreover; I write  then on the second just beacues. I only wanted my second request work and then i was going to change it

Comment: What is in network tab in develop tools? Why it is not completing? It maybe server-side issue.

Comment: i found something weird. i use the response id as the parameter in the second request  and everything went well until i did a four request, it threw me an exception

Comment: So, what exception tells?

Comment: I wrote the details in the update section